# Identifying Selection in Gridview, populated with images Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have `GridView` populated with images of 6 fruits (from `drawable-hdpi`). like this:
[image: this is how my gridview is populated with 6 types of fruits]

Now on selection, how can I come to know, what fruit the user has selected? Since I'm populating my images from `drawables-hdpi`, what would be the identifier and how to identify selection through it?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can create static array of your image ids and then it would be easier to identify the selection

Comment: @Mitesh i'm sorry, this is first time i'm playing with images. can you tell me, how does the id of my drawables-hdpi images look like? and where can i get it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
private int imageList[] = { R.drawable.image_01, R.drawable.image_02,
    R.drawable.image_03, R.drawable.image_04, R.drawable.image_05
 };
```

`OnClick`, you can get the image id and display the image if needed

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         // Here you can do the necessary operation

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's your first time with GridView and images, so why haven't you started from developer.android.com? [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) you have an answer to your question.